# Where and Or Where clause in a single query ? Using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is what I am trying to achieve : `select * from 'mytable' where id=2 and where status=hold or status=reserved or status=deleted`

How do I do this in **CodeIgniter 3.0** ?

I am working in WAMP setup.

Comment: Your query seems ill 2 where in single query without a table name... why do you wanna achieve that ?

Answer (score 3):

In `CodeIgniter` you can use like that:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('mytable');
$this->db->where('id',2);
$this->db->or_where('status','hold');
$this->db->or_where('status','reserved');
$this->db->or_where('status','deleted');
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result_array(); // will return result in array format
```

**[CodeIgniter User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=or_where#CI_DB_query_builder::or_where)**

Comment: Yeah I should :( my bad.

Comment: `echo $this->db->last_query();` what is the output  ?? It outputs `SELECT * FROM (mytable) WHERE id = 2 OR status = 'hold' OR status = 'reserved' OR status = 'deleted'` and OP wants `SELECT * FROM (mytable) WHERE id = 2 AND  (status = 'hold' OR status = 'reserved' OR status = 'deleted')` i think... BTW nice try

Comment: @praveen Kumar ok thatz nice

Comment: @PraveenKumar: than your answer is wrong maybe friend :p

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help   :

```
$results = $this->db->where("id",2)->where_in('status',array("hold","deleted","reserved"))->get("mytable")->result();
```

Comment: I was waiting for someone to post a solution with IN instead of all this OR's, +1

Comment: Awesome with `in`.+1 :)

Comment: ohh yes, you can also achieve this by using IN. thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Query in **CodeIgniter**:

```
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('tbl_name');
$this->db->where('id',2);
$this->db->or_where('status','hold');
$this->db->or_where('status','reserved');
$this->db->or_where('status','deleted');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use   $this->db->query() for this.

```
 $query= $this->db->query("select * from mytable where id=2 and (status='hold' or status='reserved' or status='deleted')");
$result=$query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('mytable');
$this->db->where('id',2);
$this->db->where('status','hold');
$this->db->or_where('status','reserved');
$this->db->or_where('status','deleted');
$query = $this->db->get();
$query->result_array();
```

Comment: While providing the code is useful, also explain your code so that your answer is useful to all readers.

Answer (score 0):

Correct SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = '2' AND (status = 'hold' 
OR status = 'reserved' OR status = 'deleted')
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha, got it. Just in case somebody else is struggling with the same situation here is how it can be dealt in CodeIgniter.

In CodeIgniter we can write our own clause manually like this :

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below mentioned query -

```
select * from tbl_name where id=2 and status in ('hold','reserved','deleted');
```